# Adding navigation to a section in an R markdown file

Tags: r

I have a navbar defined in the `_site.yml` file:

```
name: "Rmarkdown with navbar"                                
output_dir: "."
navbar:
  title: "Data Analysis"                            
  type: inverse
  right:
    - text: "Abstract"
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com                   
    - text: "Data Preparing"
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
    - text: "Related Plots"
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
    - text: "Player Selection"
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
    - text: "Conclusion"
      href: https://www.stackoverflow.com  
output:
  html_document:
    theme: spacelab
    highlight: textmate
```

I would like to be able to navigate to each section in my main rmd file, each section is defined as:

```
<section id="name-of-section">
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work (in the `_site.yml` file).

```
right:
   - text: "Abstract"
     href: #abstract
```

I would really appreciate any help. It would be even better if I could add navigation animation when clicking (I know it's achievable using jQuery in websites).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try just adding titles and subtitles to your markdown with '#' and "##' and then search for any section in "online document" (Crtl + Shift + "O")

[image]

Or you want a navigation panel on the markdown's output document?
If this is the case, have you try something like this at the beginning of your markdown?

```
---
title: "El Code-Book de Guibi"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
    toc_float: yes
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '5'
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: 72
---
```

In my case, it shows output like this:

[image]

Comment: The second one is my desired outcome

Comment: I've just edited the answer; I hope it could be usefull.